# Adding two durations together with Datejs or Momentjs, and formating them like "HH:mm:ss"

Tags: javascript, momentjs, datejs

I would like to add 2 durations together for example:
    00:04:00 + 07:23:00 = 07:27:00

```
    var std_count = "00:06:00";
    var std_create = "07:23:00";

    var time_2 = moment.duration(std_count, "HH:mm:ss");
    var time_3 = moment.duration(std_create, "HH:mm:ss");
    var final = time_2.add(time_3, "HH:mm:ss");
```

ps. I was unnable to find this kind of addition in moment js or date js. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/

Comment: I just can't figure it out, i have updated my code.

Comment: These aren't times, these are durations. Check out the documentation on duration.

Comment: Any idea how to format duration with momentjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [DateJS](http://datejs.com) with **time.js** included, you can take advantage of the **TimeSpan** class.

**Example**

```
var std_count = Date.parse("00:06:00").getTimeOfDay();
var std_create = Date.parse("07:23:00").getTimeOfDay();

var final = std_count.add(std_create);

final.toString("HH:mm:ss");
// "07:29:00"
```

or you could pull this off in one chained sequence:

```
Date.parse("00:06:00")
    .getTimeOfDay()
    .add(Date.parse("07:23:00").getTimeOfDay())
    .toString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's way more elegant solution than mine.

Comment: ps. you could include time.js on the datejs.com documentation or download page.

Comment: the time.js file is available in the .zip download package. https://code.google.com/archive/p/datejs/downloads. It was also documented at one point, but seems to be missing now. The GitHub project wiki should be updated with the documentation.

Comment: when i posted the comment i had already found it(copied it from github), and had it working. The comment was merely just an observation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var std_count = "00:04:00";
    var std_create = "07:23:00";
    var final_hours = moment.duration(std_count, "HH:mm:ss").add(std_create, "HH:mm:ss").hours();
    var final_minutes = moment.duration(std_count, "HH:mm:ss").add(std_create, "HH:mm:ss").minutes();
    var final_seconds = moment.duration(std_count, "HH:mm:ss").add(std_create, "HH:mm:ss").seconds();

    var final_calc = final_hours*3600+final_minutes*60+final_seconds;

    alert(moment.duration(final_calc, "seconds").format("HH:mm:ss"));

    Output : "07:27:00"
```

ps. moment.js and moment-duration-format.js must be included.